# How to properly correct for XY image drift using a python script?

Tags: python, image-processing, fft, scikit-image, cross-correlation

I'm new at coding and this is my first post!
As a first serious task, I'm trying to implement a simple image drift correction routine in python (so I do not need to rely on ImageJ plugins) using skimage features such as register_translation and fourier_shift.

Below you can find what I've done so far,
but here's my main questions regarding the approach:

Is the shift correction well applied?

.one thing that is not clear to me when we apply the cross-correlation peak by an FFT to identify the relative shift, is how this approach distinguishes between 'artifact' image drift and real object movement? (i.e real pixel intensity shift).

. I measured the drift for every two consecutive images and corrected the time-lapse accordingly. is there a better way to do it?

. so far I think I managed to correct at least partially the drift in my movies, but the final output still shows 1 pixel drift in a random direction, and my tiff movies look like they are 'flickering' (due to the pixel). but i should apply the drift correction in a different way!?

Looking forward for some insight, not only for my specific question but in this topic in general.

```
# import the basics

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage import data
from skimage.feature import register_translation
from scipy.ndimage import fourier_shift
from skimage import io

'''  register translation estimates the cross-correlation peak by an FFT
i.e, identifies the relative shift between two similar-sized images
using cross-correlation in Fourier space '''

movie = mymovie
shifts = []
corrected_shift_movie = []

for img in range(0,movie.shape[0]):
    if img < movie.shape[0] - 1:

        shift, error, diffphase = register_translation(movie[0], movie[img + 1])

        img_corr = fourier_shift(np.fft.fftn(movie[img + 1]), shift)
        img_corr = np.fft.ifftn(img_corr)

        shifts.append(shift)
        corrected_shift_movie.append(img_corr.real)


# for plotting the xy shifts over time

shifts = np.array(shifts)
corrected_shift_movie = np.array(corrected_shift_movie)

x_drift = [shifts[i][0] for i in range(0,shifts.shape[0])]
y_drift = [shifts[i][1] for i in range(0,shifts.shape[0])]

plt.plot(x_drift, '--g' , label = ' X drift')
plt.plot(y_drift, '--r' , label = ' Y drfit')
plt.legend()

# checking drift for the new corrected movie

movie = corrected_shift_movie
shifts_corr = []

for img in range(0,movie.shape[0]):
    if img < movie.shape[0] - 1:

        shift, error, diffphase = register_translation(movie[0], movie[img + 1])
        shifts_corr.append(shift)

shifts_corr = np.array(shifts_corr)

x_drift = [shifts_corr[i][0] for i in range(0,shifts_corr.shape[0])]
y_drift = [shifts_corr[i][1] for i in range(0,shifts_corr.shape[0])]

plt.plot(x_drift, '--g' , label = ' X drift')
plt.plot(y_drift, '--r' , label = ' Y drfit')
plt.legend()

# saving the new corrected movie

import tifffile as tiff
movie_to_save = corrected_shift_movie

with tiff.TiffWriter('drift_correction.tif', bigtiff=True) as tif:
        for new_image in range(movie_to_save.shape[0]):
            tif.save(movie_to_save[new_image], compress=0)
```

Comment: Please read [ask]

Comment: your question is very broad ... good questions zero onto a single nugget showing code such that the perspective helper gleans knowledge and so is rewarded for reading and possibly answering the question ... also such a focused question is more easily searched and found by folks asking similar questions ...  think of a good question as a single purpose method or function ...    welcome to SO

Comment: i understand that I should be more specific next time, sorry for that :/ my goal was to understand the more efficient way to implement shift correction in python.